# Increase width of systablelookup to remove horizontal scroll bar (out of 3 columns only 2 are shown) - Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: width, axapta, lookup, horizontal-scrolling, dynamics-ax-2012

Googled a lot on this but didn't find any solution. Here is the problem:

I've created a lookup using systablelookup. The lookup is working fine and is returning the selected field. **The problem is with the number of columns shown on dropping the dropdown. I've added 3 columns (Col1, Col2, Col3)**, but the lookup shows 2 columns col1 and col2 with a horizontal scroll bar. The col3 appears only when you scroll using horizontal scroll bar.

Please suggest solution to remove horizontal scroll bar from systablelookup.

Regards,
Maninder

Answer (score 2):

The way `SysTableLookup` works is it dynamically builds the controls. You can see how it does this in `\Classes\SysTableLookupBase\formRun`

To accomplish what you want, you need to extend the class `SysTableLookup` and override `buildGrid` or `buildControlsFinal` or some other method and through code make the form changes you want.

Comment: Especially calling `grid.autoSizeColumns(false);` will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Jan, are you suggesting to write this in form init() method?

Comment: Alex,  can you please suggest what to write in buildgrid or buildcontrolsfinal  method to overcome the issue such that all 3 columns are visible in one go.